TP4056 circuit with Raspberry PI pico doesn't charge battery
I assembled the following circuit as shown in the picture. VBUS is connected to VBUS on the Raspberry Pi Pico, and VBAT to VSYS on the Raspberry Pi Pico. If the battery (LiPo) is not connected, the voltage between pins 3 and 5 of the TP4056 circuit is around 4.2V. When I connect the battery, I measure the same voltage between pins 3 and 5 as the battery voltage, and the battery itself does not charge. Do you have any idea what could be wrong or where the problem might be?


Is a wire "9" present with TP4056 .

What are the states of the LEDs when the battery is connected?

R1 should be 0.4 Ohm, not 470 Ohm, between 0.5 and 0.2. Confusion between R1 and R1 ?

You should check your resistor's values
Here are the two problems identified ...


Yes! The problem was caused by resistor R1, which was supposed to have a value of 0.4 ohms but had 470 ohms. Thank you, everyone!
